# How can I access an NSMutableArray in a different class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I declare the following in **ViewController.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *locations;
```

and the following in **ViewController.m**

```
@implementation GHViewController
@synthesize locations;
...
for (FSFourSquareVenueObject *object in array) {
        locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [locations addObject:object.locationName];
        NSLog(@"%@", locations);
    }
```

This successfully logs all the string locations that have been placed in the `locations` `NSMutableArray`.  How can I access this `NSMutableArray` in a different class?

I am trying to access it in my `TableViewController` class in order to display all the elements in the array.  I have tried importing the `ViewController.h` file into my `TableViewController.h` file, yet I still cannot access the array from the `ViewController` class.

Comment: It's almost always a bad idea to expose a mutable collection in the public interface

Answer (score 2):

Remove the line

```
locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

from your for loop and place it somewhere like `viewDidLoad` or `init`. You're wiping out your array every time before adding a new object.

To access a single object across classes, you want to look into creating a singleton. There are many tutorials online.

Comment: What? We can't tell where that line is. It could very well be in either of those methods.

Comment: @Chuck doesn't matter, because a new array is being created with every iteration of the loop. But yes, the important part is that it is outside the loop, not where it is called from

Answer (score 0):

Do as [@Stonz2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23963401/1932968) suggests, but also modify your headers as follows:

In **GHViewController.h**:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *locations;
```

In **GHViewController.m**

```
@implementation GHViewController
@synthesize locations;
...
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (FSFourSquareVenueObject *object in array) {
    [array addObject:object.locationName];
    NSLog(@"%@", array);
}
self.locations = [array copy];
```

You can then access the array from another class using `GHViewController -locations`. You can edit the locations using the following snippet (or by creating a similar method in GHViewController):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [gh_viewController.locations mutableCopy];
[array addObject: newLocation];
gh_viewController.locations = [array copy];
```

Exposing a mutable array allows other class to modify the array without notifying `GHViewController` and vice versa. This can lead to unpredictable and hard to debug problems, such as if `GHViewController` removes some elements while `TableViewController` is iterating through all the objects. Using a non-mutable array prevents these sorts of bugs and ensures everyone has a consistent view of what's inside.